What's the cost of finding $(x,y)$ such that $g(f(x),y)=1$ via Grover?
I have two functions $f:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^m$ and $g: \{0,1\}^m \times \{0,1\}^k\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and I want to find a point $(x,y)$ such that $g(f(x),y)=1$ (let's assume there is only one). Can I do it quantum time $O(2^{\frac{n}{2}}(F+2^{\frac{k}{2}}G))$, where $F$ and $G$ are time complexities of $f$ and $g$ respectively? Any reference would be of great help.

In this work Estimating quantum speedups for lattice sieves: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1161.pdf, in section 3 they define the notion of a `filtered quantum search'. I think you should be able to use the $f$ in your problem as a filter and recover a complexity similar to what you mention. The idea would be to chain the search, with $f$ as the filter.
PS: Ideally this should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep for that.
